# Fixed div inside other div after certain scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fixed

I have a div inside another div like this:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

I want, with jQuery, to make *child* fixed as long as it stays inside his parent.. I've tried something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var y = $(document).scrollTop();

if(y >= $(".child").offset().top)  {
        $(".child").css("position", "fixed");
    } else {
        $(".child").css("position", "relative");
    }
});
```

But it (obviously) just makes it fixed. I want to make it fixed until it "hits" the bottom border of his parent. What should I do?

EDIT: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Hr/

Comment: can you please make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Hr/ @AmitSoni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var parent_top = $(".parent").offset().top;
var parent_bottom = $(".parent").offset().top + $(".parent").height() - $(".child").height();

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(document).scrollTop();

  if(y >= parent_top && y <= parent_bottom)  {
    $(".child").css({"position": "fixed", "top" : "0px"});
  } else {
    $(".child").css("position", "relative");
  }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d5nhd/1/)**